# how developer hack his own website by creating new session manually? (with out login)

Tags: php, security, session, session-cookies

I read many question and post about my question but all were not helpful.

I develop website, and in login page i use session.
As i know session is end when browser close,, but my session is not end on browser close..

I want to access my web with out login 
here is code that create session

```
  $_SESSION['session_name'] = 'session value';
  $_SESSION['is_admin'] = '1';
  $general->redirect('home.php');
```

by this code session is created and i access website definitely,

i try to add session manually , and set these session name in manually session, and then i want to access website,..

you Not give me full detail, but please give me initialize suggestion and helpful source where i read about this.

Thank you.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? If you have a `session_start()` before you create the `$_SESSION` variables this should work. Are you sure your `$_SESSION` variables are not overwritten somewhere?

Comment: Every thing working oK, i want to create session with out any programming, like we create cookies with help of add on, then use cookies.. same like that, i want to create session and then want to exces website.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a separate page on your website’s root (preferably protected by a HTACCESS password). Call it something like *hack_login.php* (or something more cryptic).

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['session_name'] = 'session value';
$_SESSION['is_admin'] = '1';
?>
```

Now when you access that page, and provided your session cookie is written correctly, you should be authorized when you access your website through the front page.

Don't forget to remove that page once your tests are done ;)

Comment: I already apply this in my site by url parameter..,but i don't want this,i want to access my website as a hacker.. think in website no hack.ph or any url parametr string, so how you access this web if you are a website developer.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I don't understand your question. Do you need to test if your authentication method is secure?

Comment: i appreciate your answer, but i want to create session without any programming, please tell me, is this possible i create session in browser?, or with help of any addon?

Comment: You could use cookies. Set your script to set the session variables in response to a cookie, and then set your cookie values manually in your browsser.

Comment: Could you provide me any help full source where i read full ,